# How to use `filterBy` with has_many relationship Ember Cli?

Tags: ember.js

There are two `models`: `mevent` and `mcalendar`.
`mcalendar` has_many `mevents`.
I have this code in my `afterModel` hook, I would like to filter `mevents` of `mcalendar` by one of `mevent` property. How can I do it?

```
 afterModel: function () {

var _this = this;
var model = this.modelFor(this.routeName);

  return model.get('mevents').then(function(mevents) {
    var allMevents = mevents.map(function(mevent){
      return {
                title: mevent.get('title'),
                start: mevent.get('start')
              };
    });
```

I tried to use `filterBy`,but it did not work.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work". Was there an error? Did it behave differently to what you expected?

Comment: `allMevents` was empty, no error.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_filterBy

Comment: I checked it out, but it works in half way. The problem is , If I get all `mevents` for the specific `mcalendar` then I am not able to filter them and if I filter `mevents`  first then I am not able to get its `mcalendar`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally a better place for that code would be in your controller as a computed property:

```
// mCalendar controller
mEvents: Ember.computed.map("model.mevents", function(mEvent) {
  return {
    title: mEvent.get('title'),
    start: mEvent.get('start')
  };
})
```

though I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with the map

Comment: You should probably use `model.mevents.@each.{title, start}` as your dependent key.

Comment: The goal is to make an array which will be used by `fullCalendar` which is a `component` in the application. `allMevents` will be set for `controller`. I gave a try to  your code, but seems array is empty besides `fullcalendar` did not show up at all. I changed the dependent key, `fullcalendar` showed up but there was no data. Thanks for you answer though. Any recommandation would be nice.

Comment: If you can put together an ember-twiddle illustrating your problem, I'll take a look.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. After, trying a lot of ways, I found combination of `store` `find` along modifying `rails` actions might be the best approach.     I change one part of the code to this one, and it works very well : `this.store.find('mevent', {mcalendar_id: params.get('id')})`...   by the way thanks for offer.